# New tires, front brakes and rotors on 2010 VW CC Sport

Tags: brakes, vw, frontend, cc-sport

Clunking noise became worse over next few days. Was told caliper bracket bolt was lost. Also parking brake light stayed on. My question is, what all damage could have occurred to my car? Could it affect my new tires brakes rotors? What else should I have checked just in case?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not quite sure I understand what your circumstances are? From what I'm reading, it appears you had the brakes/rotors/tires replaced with new, but one of the caliper bracket bolts fell out after installation. Now you're wondering what damage may have occurred?

Comment: That’s correct, I just want to make sure to ask them about everything that they checked or replaced so I can get in writing. Anything that could be related that just gets brushed under the carpet.